# Check if a role in PostgreSQL has a password set

Tags: postgresql, admin

I wonder how I can verify whether or not a role (users are just a specific kind of role) has a password set in PostgreSQL 9.1.

I tried the command `\dg+` and `\du+` but they don't show you anything password related. I also used the following query, but it doesn't help either because of its indifference (I'm quite sure that the postgresql user has no password set in this case):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_user;

 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd | userepl |  passwd  | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t         | t       | ******** |          | 
 aef      |    16201 | t           | t        | t         | t       | ******** |          |
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Passwords are stored in [pg_shadow](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-shadow.html)

In documentation:

> Password (possibly encrypted); null if none. See pg_authid for details
>   of how encrypted passwords are stored.

So you should `select * from pg_shadow;`

You should also check [pg_authid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-authid.html) table.

Comment: Note, you must be a PostgreSQL superuser to access those tables. On RDS you're an RDS_SUPERUSER which is not equivalent and you cannot access those tables.

Comment: Checking pg_authid table also helps to determine if the passwords are stored encrypted (as they should be).